# How do I get printer ink levels from the command line?

Tags: cups, printing

I am using CUPS 2.4.2 for printing on FreeBSD 13.1. In `/usr/local/etc/cups/printers.conf`, I noticed that CUPS knows the ink levels of my printer. Excerpt:

```
<Printer myprinter>
...
Attribute marker-levels 0,90
Attribute marker-low-levels 15,15
Attribute marker-high-levels 100,100
Attribute marker-names Color,Black
...
</Printer>
```

The values above show that the color cartridge is out of ink, while the black cartridge has 90% of its ink remaining. I know that these are reasonable values because I had just replaced the black cartridge a few days ago, and my printer currently has a warning light to indicate that I should replace the color cartridge.

What is the proper way to get these ink levels from the command line?

Comment: That's a config file. It contains limits, not the current values, as far as I read it.